# How to change the From address mail id dynamically using mail composer in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, mfmailcomposer

My application has the option to log in with google account.

So by using that corresponding login email id, I need to share content through that particular email using `MFMailComposeViewController` method.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to do what you want with the **From** field. The from address will **default to mail** account the user has specified as "default" in Settings. i.e iPhone/iPad devices' "Mail". And `MFMailComposeViewController` is used to send mail with that mail account, **not the mail address you used to login your app.**

Comment: you can use "setPreferredSendingEmailAddress" for iOS 11 and newer.